# Knee pain after jogging on an inclined pavement

Tags: running, legs, knees, jogging, knee-pain

I haven't been exercising for a while, and three days ago I decided I'd go jogging outdoors. I am currently in Germany, and like most of the pavements in Germany, they are inclined towards the road to direct rain water.

I was jogging around a block in a counter-clockwise direction. After two days of running (45 minutes each I guess), I started to feel a pain in my left knee. I can tell that it is not just a muscle ache, and it is only in my left knee, which apparently was pressing against a higher ground of the pavement than my right one. It hurts when I extend my left leg while walking.

Should I worry about this? I thought next time I'd do it clockwise instead, is this a good idea?

Comment: I was born in germany and noticed the incliniation in the pavement ... also, I try to jog in a park.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should worry. I'd go see a doctor who may refer you to physio - not sure how it works in Germany sorry.

Essentially, due to the slant in the pavement, you've been putting one knee (leg) under more abnormal pressure then the other. Running in reverse around the block is probably going to cause the same pain in the other knee.

Seriously, I'd find a flat surface to run on. If need be, use a treadmill. Boring I know, but at least you can run without having to worry about causing damage to your joints.

You will end up doing some serious damage to your knee(s) by continuing to run on this slanted ground.

Doing stretches as suggested by @DizzyDrakefL0w I wouldn't recommend. You don't "stretch" joint pains!

Comment: I did consult a doctor and the answer given is very close to his advice and explanation to what happened. He suggested that I rest for 3 weeks, not to strongly bend my knee, and to avoid running on uneven floor. It is not a big deal in the end, no fractures or so, but as the answer said, continuing to run on this slanted ground could heavily damage the knees.

Comment: Good to hear you've seen a doctor and sorted it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your logic with your running direction; however, what you have is called runners knee. Its a very common knee injury where basically its inflammed from over use. There are tons of stretches you can do to be prevent this. Having a good muscular balance between your quadriceps and your hamstrings is crucial for runners to have if they're going to be doing it a lot so the knee cap is kept in place. Here is a youtube channel/video that can help you out.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDhKVtkfnsg

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should worry a bit. It could be because you are exercising after a while, but then, one must not take any risks or assumptions when it comes to health. Go and consult your physician. Till then you should try [knee extension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KshXMXS90Pg) for a quick relief